# TextBox default template

Tags: wpf, silverlight, templates

I have a TextBox and when I hover it the border changing the color to blue. How can I disable this behavior ?

XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="100">
        <TextBox></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Is this WPF or SL; you have both tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy "hack" you can use to disable the border animation when `IsMouseOver` is True is to make a small change to the `BorderThickness`. e.g `BorderThickness="1.000001"`

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="100">
        <TextBox BorderThickness="1.000001"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Unbelievable how simple it is!! :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to define a style where you remove the storyboard for the MouseOver state.
It should be like this (tested for SL):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NoMouseOverTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="#5EC9C9C9" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#A5F7F7F7" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                        <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                    <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource NoMouseOverTextBoxStyle}" />
    </Grid>
```

If you want this for all text boxes, have a look at implicit styles (http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx).

BR,

TJ

Comment: Thanks TJ but I didn't realize how to merge your code with mine

Comment: Hi Erez, see my edit. There is now a full example for a style in SL.

Comment: Thanks man but I need WPF solution and Meleak's seems to be simpler.